# Python module not reflecting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, module

I have python 3.8.2 installed. Now I need to install Numpy, pandas, Matplotlib etc. for which I am using Anaconda distribution. I finish the installation without any problems however if I use the command "Import numpy " in IDE it gives the below error -

import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import numpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Any solution?

Comment: how did you install numpy ?

Comment: I have installed it using Anaconda command prompt. "pip install numpy" and same for others like pandas etc

Comment: And are you using / activating the same virtual environment that you installed those packages ? Btw : even if you can use pip....Anaconda has also its own package management. Did you try using it ? Check it out : https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numpy

Comment: Also tried that twice. 2nd time I got the message -# All requested packages already installed. So I concluded its already installed, however when I go to python ide environment I am not getting what i expect. My installation path will make any difference? Thanks for attending my messages so quickly.:)

Comment: Just to make sure you did all those steps : 
1)  you created your virtual environment lets calll it "my_env" : "conda create -n my_env"
2) you activated this environment : activate my_env (if you are in Linux or MacOS : source activate my_env)
3) you installed all packages you need : conda install -c numpy (for example)
4) Run the program (the path does not matter once the virtual environment is activated - i.e you can see it at the beginning of your comand prompt like so : (my_env) #   

Did you do every single step I mentionned here and in this order ?